# How to add gesture to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, wkwebview

I need to add UIGestureRecognizer to WKWebView.

I set tap gesture to WKWebView and it works until web view loads url.
After url is loaded, it doesn't recognize the gesture.

Is there any way I can add gesture to WKWebView?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SwipeObserveExperimentController: UIViewController {

    let webView: WKWebView = {
        let v = WKWebView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.scrollView.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Layout
        view.addSubview( webView )
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        webView.topAnchor   .constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor     ).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor  ).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor .constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor   ).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor  .constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor    ).isActive = true


        // Gesture
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTap) )
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


        // Load URL
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.akr-ski.com/")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }



    func viewTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("View Tap")
    }

}
```

Comment: Add it after it loads the URL and if not already added.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try this

```
class SwipeObserveExperimentController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTap) )
tapGesture.delegate = self
webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

and call the following method

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
  return true
}
```

and call the function as

```
func viewTap() {
  print("View Tap")
}
```

Comment: In Swift 4, the delegate method signature has changed.

Comment: Yup, it's `func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool`

Comment: @MrRogers - Thank you, I updated the answer

Comment: Basically, this solution works. However, links stopped working in my web page. Obviously, the tap event does not get though to WKWebView anymore. Has anyone an idea how to  use two UITapGestureRecognizers at the same time (at the same touch)?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have links in my WebView which stopped working, How can i have both Gesture and external link